# Discord.py - Economy system

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Can someone please help me? I was trying to code an Economy System Bot, but it doesn't work. It just gives me a very long Error when i try to execute a command. Here's the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import random



os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\PythonEconomyBot")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "eco ")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ist online!")


@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s Kontostand",color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank",value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(em)


@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    earnings = random.randrange(101)

    await ctx.send(f"Jemand gab dir {earnings} Moneten!")


    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)


async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)]  = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True


async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users


client.run("My Token")
```

I really don't know what i did wrong, but i don't have really much experience with the discord.py module, so would be nice if someone could help.

```
Here's the Error: File 
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Please add the error, questions like "please help me" are too broad for StackOverflow, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edited the question, sorry

Comment: Does the error occur after executing a command?

Comment: Yes, it appears when i try to execute balance

Comment: Try adding an "r" in this: os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\PythonEconomyBot")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not put your JSON file into another folder you can remove your `os.chdir` path, it will be found.

*Quick tip: Paths normally have the following format: `C:/Users/user/...`*

The code looks fine to me although you did a little mistake in the following line:

```py
await ctx.send(em)
```

If you want to send an embed you always have to define it, so the right line would be:

```py
em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s Kontostand",color = discord.Color.red())
em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
em.add_field(name = "Bank",value = bank_amt)
await ctx.send(embed=em) # Added embed
```

I would also suggest you always put the functions on top of the commands/actual code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import random

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True


async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users

@client.command()
```

Remember to put `{}` into your JSON file. It should look like this before you run a command:

```py
{

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still gives me the same Error

Comment: Yes, when i try to execute beg it gives me the same error

Comment: Edited my answer with a JSON example, does that help?

Comment: No, i have my Json just like that, two curly brackets with a space inbeetween

Comment: The code snippet you sent does not throw errors for me after correcting your little `embed` mistake. It must be something else. For what do you use `os.chdir`? Have you tried to blurr that out for a second?

Comment: Ok, so without the os.chdir it sends something, but this doesn't make much sense: "<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x0000026D4DA1CDC8>"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229092/discussion-between-dominik-and-m4ximpl4yz).